# Replace picture background with video background

Tags: html, css, html5-video

What would be the quickest way to replace the picture background I currently have with a video background, while retaining all of its properties?

This is my code so far:

```
<div id="hero">
<div id="bg"></div>
<table id="outerDiv" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" id="innerDiv">
<div class="post-header"><img src="http://www.makemeapro.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
<div class="post-header"><h1 style="color: #383838;">Helping young professionals navigate the world of work.</h1></div>
<div align="center"><button class="btn">JOIN THE REVOLUTION</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zxqz7oe0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to replace the picture background with a video, would be to place the video on top of that picture, and make it cover the parent's area using [`object-fit`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#the-object-fit). It requires minor HTML and CSS changes:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
     <video autoplay loop>
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
     </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hero video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover; /* Resize the video to cover parent, like a background-size:cover */
}

#hero #bg {
  /* The styles for #bg remain the same, you'd just need to add */
  /* one more, so the video that overflows the #hero is hidden: */
  overflow:hidden; 
}
```

You can see an example working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxqz7oe0/1/

One issue of this solution is that `object-fit` is not fully supported yet: Chrome, Firefox, and Android are OK, but you may face problem on Firefox and mobile. And IE doesn't support it at all. (You can [see the browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).)

You could use this simple method, and then have a JavaScript fallback solution for the browsers that do not support `object-fit`. Knowing the video size, it would be easy to calculate the width/height needed at each moment when the window is loaded/resized.